# Encountered error(s) while parsing pipeline YAML: Did not find expected <document start>

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

I am trying to created build pipeline, I have created classic pipeline from azure portal manually(Which is working) and generated yaml code from working pipeline then created files /.azure/pipelines/ci.yml, /.azure/pipelines/build/build-ci.yml files.

Code as below

/.azure/pipelines/ci.yml

```
# File: .azure/pipelines/ci.yaml
# Pipeline for the continuous integration to verify the changeset is good enuf,
# and has no platform specific content included.
# HINT: PR triggers are setup in the branch policies.
# Learn more https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers

trigger: none

variables:
  vmImageName: 'windows-2019'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
      demands:
      - msbuild
      - visualstudio
      - vstest

    steps:
    - template: /.azure/pipelines/build/build-ci.yml
```

---

/.azure/pipelines/build/build-ci.yml

```
 parameters:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  ArtifactName: 'Some Name'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.4.1'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.4.1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(Parameters.solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
    vsVersion: 16.0
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Test Assemblies'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll
     !**\obj\**
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishSymbols@2
  displayName: 'Publish symbols path'
  inputs:
    SearchPattern: '**\bin\**\*.pdb'
    PublishSymbols: false
  continueOnError: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    ArtifactName: '$(Parameters.ArtifactName)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Getting Error while running pipeline from yaml file.

Encountered error(s) while parsing pipeline YAML:
/.azure/pipelines/build/build-ci.yml (Line: 5, Col: 1):  Did not find expected .

Comment: Did you paste this exactly as written?  Because if so you have a problem with indentation.  You have one space ` ` of indentation before `steps:`, but then none of the list items that should be under `steps:` are indented.

Comment: Thanks, 
Space was added while creating question now corrected it.

Comment: There's still a space in front of `parameters` in the first line which shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thanks   Iguananau and flyx. 
Formatting solved the problem